# How do I use the Lunar flowers?

Tags: flutter-starlight

I understand how to use and fuse different flowers to get various new butterflies/moths. However, sometimes the frog gives me Lunar flowers - these don't show up in the normal flower menu. What are they for? How do I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be high enough level to see them yet. I couldn't see them either, early on in the game, but when I leveled up more, they appeared along with the other flowers.

Eventually you can use them like normal flowers to unlock a special type of epic lunar moths.